# Array with different labels in R

Tags: arrays, r, label

I have a (simplified) Array looking like this:

```
d<-array(c(1:64), dim=c(4,4,4)) 
dimnames(d)=list( c("One", "Two", "Three","Four"),
                  c("Initial", "NUMBER", "FU1", "FU2"),
                  c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"))
```

How do I get the Label 'NUMBER' be one of the labels below "Alpha" - "Delta", depending on what Array is shown? For example, for:

```
print(d[,,2])
```

resulting in

```
      Initial NUMBER FU1 FU2
One        17     21  25  29
Two        18     22  26  30
Three      19     23  27  31
Four       20     24  28  32
```

I need the label 'NUMBER' to be 'BETA' and for

```
print(D[,,4]
```

the label to be 'DELTA'

Since I have to work on these arrays with the same procedures, creating different matrices is the solution, I want to avoid. (This is, why I work with those multi-dimensional arrays)

edit: changed labels for clarification

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to index using the labels?

Comment: No. Just for later steps (and way more variables), it would be nice to see exactly, what 'Number' (Alpha to Delta) the table refers to.

Comment: like this? `n<-4;
dimnames(d)[[3]][n];
print(d[,,n])`

Comment: You can use the argument `drop` set to `FALSE` when subsetting. Try for instance `d[,,4,drop=FALSE]`. Don't think it answers your question, but it's a way to see what the table refers to.

Comment: If you change the column name once, you change it for all. It is the same with the row names. Try `d[,2,]` to see all of the values for `NUMBER`. If you want a different column name for each piece, a `list` structure will work better.

Comment: The labels cannot be changed in the way you are seeking. It will lead to ambiguity. And there is nothing a cpu attempts to avoid more than paradoxes. Look at `dimnames(d)` to see that the structure only has three vectors of names. You are asking for four different vectors of names for the second dimension. Impossible with `array`. You want `list`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thank you very much for your input. I will give it a try tomorrow!